# How to write a function in c that counts words

Tags: c, while-loop, count, c-strings, function-definition

I had an exam yesterday in which one of the questions was about counting words in a given string.

The definition of word would be a portion of a string that is divided by spaces and/or the beginning/end of the string

I am new to C, and was not able to create a condition where it increases the counter word when you  find “space (characters) space”

```
int count_words(char *str)
int i = 0;
int word = 2;
while (str[i])
{ 
     if (str[i] == ‘ ‘)
     {
         int l = 1;
         while (str[i + l]
         {
             l++;
         }
         if (l != 1)
         {
             word++;
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: Where is `l` declared?

Comment: 1) *The definition of word would be a portion of a string that is divided by spaces and/or the beginning/end of the string.* --> Is `9` a valid word? How about `cas#$*c`? 2) Are you allowed to use functions from `ctype.h`? 3) Why is the initial value of `word` 2?

Comment: 4) Why do you not consider words like `a` and `I` valid? 5) Why do you not check for tabs and other whitespaces?

Comment: I think the definition of a word is fairly clear in the given context. There is no need to produce code which is usable in a real world application. So 9 for example is obviously a word. Same is true for the definition of characters which separate the words (no tabs or other white spaces).

Comment: It seems like you’ve copied so called “smart quotes” from MS word, a PDF, or some other program which uses them. This will cause strange compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
size_t count_words(const char *str);
```

The function parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const` because the passed string is not being changed within the function and the function return type should be `size_t` that is the same return type as for example of standard string  function `strlen`.

It is unclear why the variable `word` in your function is initialized by `2`

```
int word = 2;
```

Or the variable `i` is not being changed within the function.

The function can look the following way as shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t count_words( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( *s )
    {
        while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;

        if ( *s )
        {
            ++n;
            while ( *s && !isspace( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "How to write a function in c that counts words";

    size_t n = count_words( s );

    printf( "The string \"%s\"\ncontains %zu words\n", s, n );
}
```

The program output is

```
The string "How to write a function in c that counts words"
contains 10 words
```

If to use as delimiters only the space character `' '` then the header `<ctype.h>` should be removed and the function will look like

```
size_t count_words( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( *s )
    {
        while ( *s == ' ' ) ++s;

        if ( *s )
        {
            ++n;
            while ( *s && *s != ' ' ) ++s;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

A more general function that can process any delimiters can look the following way

```
size_t count_words( const char *s, const char *delim )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while (*s)
    {
        s += strspn( s, delim );

        if (*s)
        {
            ++n;
            s += strcspn( s, delim );
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

The function has a second parameter that specifies delimiters. For example the function can be called loke

```
size_t n = count_words( s, " \t?!:;,." );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<string.h>

# define MaxBufferSize 50
void main(){
    int count =0, size;
    char str[MaxBufferSize+2];
    printf("Enter string(max char 50 only): ");
    if(fgets(str,sizeof(str), stdin)) {
        if(strlen(str) > MaxBufferSize) printf("Max chars exceeded so chars before the limit were used!!!\n");
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
    }
    size = strlen(str);
    int i=0;
    if(size == 0) printf("Nothing entered\n");
    else {
        while(i<size){
            while(!isalnum(str[i]) && i<size) i++;// ignores all spaces and other chars
            if(str[i] == '\0') break;
            while(isalnum(str[i]) && i<size) i++;// includes all words and numbers 
            count++;
        }
        printf("Words in string: %d\n",count);
    }
}
```

hope it helps...! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int count_words(char *str) {
    int i, count=0;
    int in_word = 0; // Flag to track if we're currently inside a word or not
    
    // Loop through each character in the string
    for(i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        // If current character is not a space or newline and we're not already inside a word, increment word count
        if((str[i]!=' ' && str[i]!='\n') && !in_word) {
            count++;
            in_word = 1; // Set flag to indicate we're currently inside a word
        }
        // If current character is a space or newline, set flag to indicate we're not inside a word
        else if(str[i]==' ' || str[i]=='\n') {
            in_word = 0;
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
     
    void main()
    {
        char s[200];
        int count = 0, i;
     
        printf("Enter the string:\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", s);
        for (i = 0;s[i] != '\0';i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == ' ' && s[i+1] != ' ')
                count++;    
        }
        printf("Number of words in given string are: %d\n", count + 1);
    }
```

Use this code it will definitely works fine ):

Comment: For Better Understanding for you refer this site  https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-count-words-in-sentence/

Comment: Tried your code. Fed it the string "foobar  "... It told me there were 2 words in the string.

Comment: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", s);` -> `scanf("%199[^\n]", s);` but this will not fix the other problems and using `fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)` is a better approach anyway.